# Collection initializer and TypeInitializationException vs IEnumerable

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable, collection-initializer

I have used collection initializer for a `Dictionary` and received a `TypeInitializationException`:

```
public static Dictionary<Environment.SpecialFolder, string> specialFolders = new Dictionary<Environment.SpecialFolder, string>
{
    // ...
    {Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments, "abc"},
    // ...
    {Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal   , "def"},
    // ...
};
```

As there is no useful info like `InnerException`, call stack or whatever else it is confusing. So I investigated the problem a bit and realized that there are two keys having the same value.

Regarding the IL, this collection initializer syntax is converted to `Dictionary.Add(...)` calls and as such calling `Add` two times with the same key raises `System.ArgumentException` (which is the inner exception I would expect in the `TypeInitializationException`). So I effectivelly answered my original question, but another one has emerged:

Why the class has to implement `IEnumerable` (and thus provide `IEnumerator`) - which is intended to **read** the collection, not to write it - when finally the collection initializer is converted to `Add` call (which is not guaranteed to be present in the class via the IEnumerable)? Am I missing something important?

Comment: FYI, both special-folder enums have the same values(`Personal = 5`, `MyDocuments = 5`) and  [`Enum.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bafh2by(v=vs.110).aspx) checks if the value of two instances is equal. So this enum is is really a bad candidate for a dictionary-key.

Comment: Interesting question, I would have expected it to require something like `IList`, which would provide the `Add` and as a side effect, the `IEnumerable` interface - but that's not the case.

Comment: Dereferencing one of the answers of the mentioned question I'm duplicating - the very detailed discussion is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx